# Nginx Rewrite Paths to Base URL

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am trying to configure Nginx so that all requests to `http://domain.com/path` are rewritten to `http://domain.com/`.

I do not want a redirect, because I want the URL to still show the original path.

Example Rewrites:

```
http://domain.com/path/index.php         -> http://domain.com/index.php
http://domain.com/path/category/books    -> http://domain.com/category/books
http://domain.com/path/books.php?q=harry -> http://domain.com/books.php?q=harry
```

I tried [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) and [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) but I could not get them to work.

```
location /path
{
    root /var/www/html/;
}

location /path
{
    alias /var/www/html/;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`root` and `alias` are meant to serve files from a specific directory not rewriting URL. You should use `rewrite`.

```
server {
    rewrite ^/path(/.*)$ $1 last;

    # Your location blocks go here.
}
```

Read [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more info.